# Curses Window in linux is not appearing physically on screen. But it is virtually present in the background and takes input also

Tags: linux, perl, curses

Curses Window in linux is **not** appearing physically on screen. But it is **virtually present** in the background and takes input also. What might be the issue?

The same code works fine in AIX and Solaris Machines but not in SUSE, RedHat or any other Linux machines.

**Part of my code is below:**

```
my $screen = newwin(40,40,1,1);

$screen->clrtoeol();
$screen->addstr( 20,20,"Hello World" );
$screen->standend();
$screen->refresh();
```

Comment: - try to check used terminal emulators terminfo/termcap
- check the application in other teminal, like xterm

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using **putty** as a client to connect to Linux machine. I am not very sure about the usage of terminfo. Please let me know if I can try anything else. I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: What is `InstallUI::MenuScreen`? I could not find the module on CPAN..

Comment: Sorry. That was something specific to our framework. I have changed the code to a generic one now. Please check.

Comment: @OP Hi, MVCE isn't an offence word, it means a minimal complete program. Please provide one